# Need help in understanding Hbase Read Path

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I've been doing some research on HBase and I'm currently finding challenges in understanding how HBase read path works.  I have a basic understanding of how it works. But, I don't have clear understanding of how it reads multiple HFiles checking bloom filters. Whats the purpose of metablocks, how hbase uses it for reading the data. Whats the purpose of indexes in hfiles, and how its used ?

Hence needed your help in understanding this concept.

Your time is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are more than one HFile at the time of read, HBase will check whether the row in question is there or not. If it is there HBase will read that row from all the HFiles(and also from memstore), so that client always gets the latest data. I'm sorry didn't quite get `block filters` thing. Could you please point me to the source where you have read about this? That'll help me in providing you the complete answer.(Do you mean Bloom Filter?)

Purpose of metablock is to keep large amount of data. Metablocks are used by HFile to store a BloomFilter and a string key is associated with each metablock. Metablocks are kept in memory until HFile.close() is called.

An Index is written for metablocks to make reads faster. These indices contains n records (where n is the number of blocks) with block information (block offset, size and first key). 
And at the end a Fixed File Trailer is written to the HFile. It contains offsets and counts for all the HFile Indices, HFile Version, Compression Codec etc. Now when read starts first of all `HFile.loadFileInfo()` gets called and File Trailers, which were written earlier are loaded into the memory along with all the indices. It allows to query keys efficiently. Then with the help of `HFileScanner` client seeks to a specified key, and iterate over it to read the data.

I would like to to point you to the links which had helped in understanding these things. Hopefully you'll find them useful.

[Link 1: Apache HBase I/O – HFile (Cloudera)](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-io-hfile-input-output/)

[Link 2: HBase I/O: HFile (th30z)](http://th30z.blogspot.in/2011/02/hbase-io-hfile.html)

[Link 3: Scanning in HBase](http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.in/2012/01/scanning-in-hbase.html)

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped a lot understanding about Hfiles. Need some more explanation on read path..For example if we have 5 Hfiles, and 2 Hfiles contain the key we are looking for...And say for this key, some value is present in memstore as well, with this can you explain, how the flow would be ?? will bloom filter present in 5 HFiles be loaded into memory??

Comment: You are welcome ma'am :)..Let me try..If you have 5 HFiles then in the normal scenario all the 5 files be scanned in a parallel 5-way manner to get that particular row, which implies you are doing 5 disk reads. But if you have BF enabled you disk reads will be reduced to only the files likely to contain that particular row i.e 5-2 in this case. BFs will be loaded for all the opened HFiles. Does this sound OK?Or do I need to elaborate it further?

Comment: If the key is found in memstore then is it done and can return already? Can the key in HFile be newer than the one in memstore?